# Error :: Main method not found in class

Tags: java

When I run my code, I receive this error message:

```
Error: Main method not found in class "Class name", please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

My code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    public void printPhoto(int width,int height, boolean inColor){
        System.out.println("Width = " + width +  " cm" );
        System.out.println("Height = " + height + " cm");
        if(inColor){
            System.out.println("Print is Full color.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Print is black and white.");
        }
        printPhoto(10,20,false);
    }
}
```

Comment: isn't the error clear enough ? BTW. You need to show us the code for the main method, if indeed there is one. Make sure it is `public static void main(String args[])`

Comment: Then create a `public static void main(String[] args)` in your class?

Comment: World's Smaile did not ask the question in correct context. Its a problem with Jetbrains idea IDE. I am also having the same problem. I am a seasoned programmer and my class and main method are all correct but when run from inside the idea community edition, it is showing this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a java program you need the main method which not define in your code you can make it like this :

```
public class Test {

    public void printPhoto(int width, int height, boolean inColor) {
        System.out.println("Width = " + width + " cm");
        System.out.println("Height = " + height + " cm");
        if (inColor) {
            System.out.println("Print is Full color.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Print is black and white.");
        }
        // printPhoto(10, 20, false); // Avoid a Stack Overflow due the recursive call
    }

    //main class
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test tst = new Test();//create a new instance of your class
        tst.printPhoto(0, 0, true);//call your method with some values        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As already [@YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l) posted, you need the main method.

First, make sure you remove:

```
printPhoto(10,20,false);
```

to avoid a Stack Overflow due the recursive call.

If you need to create a new instance and directly use your method, you can do the following:

```
public class Test {

    public Test printPhoto(int width, int height, boolean inColor) {
        System.out.println("Width = " + width + " cm");
        System.out.println("Height = " + height + " cm");
        if (inColor) {
            System.out.println("Print is Full color.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Print is black and white.");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test testObj = new Test().printPhoto(10, 20, false); //Creates a new instance of your class Test and calls the method printPhoto
    }

}
```

Alternatively, you could also make the method static, but it's not always the best procedure, it depends on how you are going to use it.

```
public class Test {

    public static void printPhoto(int width, int height, boolean inColor) {
        System.out.println("Width = " + width + " cm");
        System.out.println("Height = " + height + " cm");
        if (inColor) {
            System.out.println("Print is Full color.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Print is black and white.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPhoto(10, 20, false);
    }

}
```